# cakephp field naming conventions - saving multiple models

Tags: cakephp

```
Chart hasMany Series
Series belongsTo Chart
Series hasAndBelongsToMany Industry
Series hasAndBelongsToMany Sector
Industry hasMany Sector
Sector belongsTo Industry
```

I am trying to allow users to save the Chart along with multiple Series.

How should I name the input fields and what save methods to call to save all the Models along?

Answer (score 0):

The normal convention to save multiple associated model values at once is as following:

```
$data = array(
    'User' => array('userFieldName' => 'fieldValue'),
        'Chart' => array(
            array(
                'chartFieldName' => "chartFieldValue",
                'Series' => array(
                    array(
                        'firstSerieItemField' => "Value",
                    ),
                    array(
                        'secondSerieItemField' => "Value",
                    )
                    ...
                    ...//More Series Data
                )
            )
        )
    );

$this->User->saveAll($data);
```

****Note: don't forget to assign relationships between models****

But you could achieve it by defining field values properly in you view page. just remember to follow the pattern:

```
topMdel["topModelFieldName"];
topModel["FirstAssociateModel"]["FirstAssociateModelFieldName"];
topModel["FirstAssociateModel"]["SecondAssociateModel"]["SecondAssociateModelFieldName"];
```

To be more clear. in your case:

For Usermodel data fields:

```
User["user_name"];
User["user_email"]; //etc.
```

For Chart model data fields:

```
User["Chart"]["chart_name"];
User["Chart"]["chart_value"]; //etc.
```

hope that helps.
For Series model data fields:

```
User["Chart"]["Series"][0]["series_1_name"]; 
User["Chart"]["Series"][1]["series_2_name"]; 
User["Chart"]["Series"][2]["series_2_name"];
```